# Building tests in Intellij for Play Framework is very slow

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.3

Is there a way to speed up the build time of unit tests for Play Framework in Intellij? I am doing TDD. Whenever I execute a test, it takes about 30 - 60 seconds to compile. Even a simple *Hello World* test takes time. Rerunning the same test even without any change will still start the *make* process.

I am on Intellij 14.1, on Play 2.3.8, written in Scala.

I already tried setting the java compiler to eclipse, and also tried setting Scala compiler to SBT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you know that the problem is build-time - that the actual run-time for the tests themselves is negligible.

What do you have for hardware?  In my experience, 4GB RAM is not enough for Intellij Scala to perform well - it needs a big disk cache (which the OS uses free RAM for), I think.  An SSD helps, too.  Use Performance Monitor or analogous for your OS to see whether the time is disk, CPU, or net.  If it's CPU, consider whether heap-size may be a problem.

What is your build process like?  Are there sbt plugins?  How big is your project?

UPDATE

Triggering a full rebuild without changes is wrong.  Is there something in your tests that is modifying the project directories?  If you run a dummy no-op test, does it do the same thing?  Are you maybe writing logs into the project tree, for instance?

In my limited experience, *full* Play builds under Intellij are orders of magnitude slower than a pure Scala build - I'd guess because of all the SBT plugins (view compiler, xScript compiler, xSS compiler, etc) that have to run.  But incrementals aren't that painful.

On OSX, read "Activity Monitor" for "Performance Monitor".

UPDATE

See [Intellij issue SCL-8235](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-8235) for other folks' experience and workarounds for slow incremental Play builds.  Vote for the issue to increase its priority and get it fixed quicker.

Comment: Yes! Sorry for the description. What I meant was the build time. I am running on 8GB mid 2012 mac machine. Sad to say, it's on 5400rpm HDD. Do you mean to ask SBT plugins in Intellij? If yes, I have them. The project is a microservice, and it's even on early stage so it's still small.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't seem to be a full rebuild. The messages goes as follows (if only one class is modified) [uploaded in pastebin](http://pastebin.com/G0WuTPHt)

Comment: And you're right about incrementals not being too painful, but still, Play compiler takes at least 15 seconds to start building, and building takes 1-2 seconds for a few change. In the activity monitor, I don't see any issue with the CPU. Even increasing the heap for *make* doesn't seem to help. I will be upgrading my HDD to SSD and hopefully this helps. Thanks a bunch for your help.

Comment: @jespeno Read, vote for, follow: [Intellij issue SCL-8235](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-8235)

Comment: Got it! There were some work around within the comment section. I guess I'll try to use them  first. Thanks a lot! Could you update your answer with the tracker link? I will mark your answerr as the answer.

Comment: @jespeno Updated.  Write back (maybe an answer) if something works well for you!

Comment: I added an answer. So basically, I just stopped Intellij from invoking `make` and delegated the compilation to a separate sbt process.

Answer (score 3):

In intellij 14.1.2, the workaround I did is to:

1) Remove `make` from tests (`Edit Configurations` -> `Defaults` -> `Scala Test` -> `Before launch` -> (-) `Make`)

2) Start `activator` (or `play`) with `~ test:compile` (ex: `activator ~test:compile`) or (`sbt ~ test:compile`)

This prevents Intellij from calling a play compilation server every time a `make` is invoked. The compilation is delegated to an external sbt/activator/play process to do the continuous compilation. The disadvantage is that, when you run your test immediately before the compilation completes, you may get a NoClassDefinedFound exception. Also, you will need to monitor an extra process. This setup however, is so much faster compared to the default setup by Intellij (for now). Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

What about unmarking existing tests and leaving only yours? Right click on test directory (which should be green) and `Unmark as Test Source Root`.

Comment: Often, when I refactor, I still need to run all the other test every now and then (maybe every 40 mins or so), so this is not an option for me :(

Comment: Did you look at `sbt test-only` feature?

Comment: Is this supported by SBT plugin? I can't find the option to tweak it. Also, according to the build messages, Intellij 14.1 is using Play Compiler to compile the sources.

Comment: Its a `sbt` feature to run selected tests only. See also `sbt test-quick`. http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing.html

Comment: Thanks for the link! I tried running sbt test from terminal. It seems that the runtime is the same for the IDE. It takes 10 - 12 secs for SBT to boot. And 1-2 secs to compile little changes. Also, the bad thing is, if my IDE compiles first, running sbt test will recompile everything (and coming back to IDE, the IDE will compile everything again and so on ...)